# How to edit and replace a group of lines of a text file using c#?

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a large text file(20MB), and I'm trying to change every *4th* & *5th* line to `0,0`

[image]

I've tried with the following code but I will be interested to know if theres any better way of doing it..

**EDIT:**

```
        Power = new List<float>();
        Time = new List<float>();

        string line;
        float _i =0.0f;
        float _q =0.0f;
        int counter = 0;
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(iqFile2Open);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (Regex.Matches(line, @"[a-zA-Z]").Count == 0)
            {
                string[] IQ = line.Split(',');
                if (IQ.Length == 2)
                {
                    _i = float.Parse(IQ[0]);
                    _q = float.Parse(IQ[1]);
                    double _p = 10 * (Math.Log10((_i * _i) + (_q * _q)));

                    if((counter%4)==0 || (counter%5)==0)
                        sw.WriteLine("0,0");
                    else
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", _i, _q));

                    counter++;
                }
            }                
        }
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: What did you try exactly? And why isn't `for` effective?

Comment: Include your non-working code so that we can see what isn't working for you.

Comment: *is there any better way of doing it* Show us the way you tried. We'll tell you better way if any!

Comment: Brain dump: you may try parallel open the file at different points (keep the order) and generate the output string... when all the parallel tasks are complete, concatenate them back into the file... dunno if that will be faster anyway...

Comment: And I agree with all of the above... what have you tried and how it does not work?

Comment: @all, apologies for not including the code, please see the edit section.

Comment: @San' If it makes you feel better, three other people posted answers with the exact same error.  Sadly, this is why it's best to include your own code in the question.  Those users may have seen your solution doing the same thing, known it wasn't working, and then thought about the problem a bit more.

Comment: @ Servy, Thanks a lot, a lesson learnt, Hope I don't repeat this mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in all of the lines, map each line to what it should be based on it's position, and then write them all out:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(inputFile)
    .Select((line, i) => ComputeLine(line, i + 1));

File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, lines);
```

As for the actual mapping, you can mod the line number by 5 to get an "every 5th item" result, and then just compare the result to the two mod values you care about.  Note that since you don't want the first item wiped out it's important that the index is 1-indexed, not zero indexed.

```
private static string ComputeLine(string line, int i)
{
    if (i % 5 == 4 || i % 5 == 0)
        return "0,0";
    else
        return line;
}
```

This streams through each line in the file, rather than loading the entire file into memory.  Because of this it's important that the input and output files be different.  You can copy the output file to the input file if needed, or you could instead use `ReadAllLines` to bring the entire file into memory (assuming the file stays suitably small) thus allowing you to write to the same file you read from.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm *not* using them on the same file.  I have a separate input an output file.  You'd copy the output file to the input file when done if required.

Answer (score -3):

What exactly are you trying to replace? Are you replacing by specific LINE or specific TEXT?

If you are looking to replace specific text you can easily do a string.Replace() method...

```
StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader("somefile");
string fileText = fileIn.Readlines();
fileText = fileText.Replace("old", "new");
//Repeat last line for all old strings.
//write file...
```

Comment: The example shown makes it clear that it's based on line number, as there were other instances of the same text he wasn't replacing on other lines.